Storing and compressing all files in a database as one BLOB: compression on the whole BLOB or each individual file?
I am working with Qt6 on a database like structure. For a backup, it is necessary to to combine and compress the DB structure in memory as one BLOB and then export it.
Generally, is it more efficient to compress each file and append to the BLOB (compression on shorter files and less memory needed for creating the backup) or on the whole binary object (compression on one large file, whole database in memory).
I assume the size of the database is in the range of ~200MB, but in cases up to 2GB.
Thanks for insights and opinions

Why do you need to hold the entire thing in memory as opposed to spitting out compressed chunks as they are generated?

And when you say "more efficient", what are you optimizing for? compression ratio? memory/cpu requirements?

You seem to be aware that there are tradeoffs in the two approaches. Only you can decide which tradeoff makes more sense for you. It depends on your situation/priorities. Try both approaches and measure the results.

It is a requirement to process all information in memory. Optimizing primarily for compression ratio.

Then compressing everything at once gives your compression algorithm the best chance.
